# Проблемы c доступом в интернет для google-maps на эмуляторе Android

Tags: android, google-maps, genymotion

Есть эмулятор. В нём прописываю точку доступа с указанием прокси и т.п., чтобы мог выходить в инет.
Браузер выходит, грузит страницы - всё ок.
Но!
Приложение гугло-карт на эмуляторе при попытке запуска упорно пишет, что нет доступа к сети.
Собственно из-за чего мучаюсь с ним. Моя прожка самописная на эмуляторе тоже не может подгрузить карту гугла. Хотя на реальном смартфоне грузит без проблем. Желательно как-то разобраться с этим и на эмуляторе - для удобства дальнейшей работы.

Может кто-то сталкивался с такой ситуацией и знает как победить?

Comment: @Demon051, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Есть альтернативные эмуляторы, которые (субъективно) намного лучше.  
Например, [Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/#!/). Чтобы на нем работали карты, нужно также [установить на него гугловые сервисы](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2528952). Это, конечно, потребует лишних 10 минут времени, но оно того определенно стоит.

Comment: Сегодня попробовал разбираться с genymotion
Разбирательство закончилось на том, что он сам не может подключиться к интернету, что необходимо при создании устройств :(
Указываю используемый прокси, порт, логин, пароль - всё однозначно верно. Пишет ошибку аутентификации прокси :(
Ну что за хрень... Кто-нибудь попадал в такую ситуацию, как побороть?